# Problemas com impressão de variaveis do tipo float

Tags: c

Olá gente estou resolvendo a [questão 1098 do URI judge](https://www.urionlinejudge.com.br/judge/pt/problems/view/1098), ele aparentemente é bem simples só tenho que imprimir os resultados de uma sequência em que o i vai de 0 até 2 aumentando 0.2 e j que vai de 1 até 3 + i, o J se repete vai de 1 até 3 cada vez que i aumenta 0.2, o jeito que o sistema quer é que os números quebrados sejam escrito com somente uma casa depois da virgula e quando inteiro os números não podem ter virgula.

Okay fiz um procedimento bonitinho e criei um condicional para os casos em que tenho que escrever como número inteiro, mas aparentemente ele só entra nele quando o número é 0 e 1 (faltando assim o caso quando o número da sequência é 2). Logo abaixo vou colocar o código, a saída desejada e a saída do meu código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main () {
   float i = 0;
   float j = 0;
   int cont = 1; 
   while (i <= 2.2){
      for (cont = 1; cont <= 3; cont++){
         if(i == 0 || i == 1 || i == 2){
             printf ("I=%.0f J=%.0f\n", i, j+i+cont);
         }else{
             printf ("I=%.1f J=%.1f\n", i, j+i+cont);
         }
      }
      i += 0.2;
      j = 0;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Saída desejada:

```
I=0 J=1
I=0 J=2
I=0 J=3
I=0.2 J=1.2
I=0.2 J=2.2
I=0.2 J=3.2
I=0.4 J=1.4
I=0.4 J=2.4
I=0.4 J=3.4
I=0.6 J=1.6
I=0.6 J=2.6
I=0.6 J=3.6
I=0.8 J=1.8
I=0.8 J=2.8
I=0.8 J=3.8
I=1 J=2
I=1 J=3
I=1 J=4
I=1.2 J=2.2
I=1.2 J=3.2
I=1.2 J=4.2
I=1.4 J=2.4
I=1.4 J=3.4
I=1.4 J=4.4
I=1.6 J=2.6
I=1.6 J=3.6
I=1.6 J=4.6
I=1.8 J=2.8
I=1.8 J=3.8
I=1.8 J=4.8
I=2 J=3
I=2 J=4
I=2 J=5
```

Saída do meu código:

```
I=0 J=1
I=0 J=2
I=0 J=3
I=0.2 J=1.2
I=0.2 J=2.2
I=0.2 J=3.2
I=0.4 J=1.4
I=0.4 J=2.4
I=0.4 J=3.4
I=0.6 J=1.6
I=0.6 J=2.6
I=0.6 J=3.6
I=0.8 J=1.8
I=0.8 J=2.8
I=0.8 J=3.8
I=1 J=2
I=1 J=3
I=1 J=4
I=1.2 J=2.2
I=1.2 J=3.2
I=1.2 J=4.2
I=1.4 J=2.4
I=1.4 J=3.4
I=1.4 J=4.4
I=1.6 J=2.6
I=1.6 J=3.6
I=1.6 J=4.6
I=1.8 J=2.8
I=1.8 J=3.8
I=1.8 J=4.8
I=2.0 J=3.0
I=2.0 J=4.0
I=2.0 J=5.0
```

Como vocês podem ver o erro só está nos ultimos três valores, no qual quando i é igual a 2 e eu não consigo entender como faço para coloca-lo em forma de inteiro sendo que na minha teoria ele deveria entrar no meu condicional.

Comment: Tome muito cuidado ao fazer comparações precisas com variáveis float (por exemplo a igualdade), a representação de números de ponto flutuante é inerentemente imprecisa (vide norma ANSI / IEEE Std 754-1985). Tente fazer um arredondamento para 1 casa decimal.

Comment: Uma opção para sua solução é tratar seus números como inteiros multiplicados por 10 e na hora de imprimir dividir por 10. `for (int i=0; i<=22; i+=2) { if (i==0 || i==10 || i ==20)...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tudo bem?
Então eu não vou saber te explicar o porque isso ocorre mas aparente a partir do momento em que ele assume o 2.0 ele não assume um valor exato mas muito próximo de 2.0 como por exemplo 2.000...1 logo ao fazer a comparação com o valor 2 ele não vai entrar na sua condicional, uma forma de resolver isso é trocando o

```c
  if(i == 0 || i == 1 || i == 2){}
```

por

```c
  if(i == 0 || i == 1.0 || i > 1.9){}
```

dessa forma ele entra no ultimo termo da condicional e não vai alterar de fato a execução ja que o codigo vai se encerrar na proxima iteração.